# Django on Apache2 (Ubuntu 16.04) reports 'No module named mysite.settings'

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I'm running Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04. I've set up a virtual server with the following settings. The virtual host has been registered with a2ensite and appears to be being accessed ok.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.factsfromfigures.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/user/mycode/mysite/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When it runs I get the following error in the Apache log.

```
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.968878 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552] mod_wsgi (pid=12278): Target WSGI script '/home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.968895 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552] mod_wsgi (pid=12278): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.968923 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.968933 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]   File "/home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.968964 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.968971 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.968988 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]     django.setup()
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.968992 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969007 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969024 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969057 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]     self._setup(name)
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969062 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969075 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969079 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969084 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969087 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969103 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552]     __import__(name)
[Thu Mar 01 17:35:00.969113 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12278] [client 192.168.1.68:61552] ImportError: No module named mysite.settings
```

The mysite settings.py file is at /home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite/settings.py

The wsgi.py file is at /home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

I'm not sure what version of python the server is accessing as I get these warning messages in the log: (I've no idea why it reports 2 different version)

```
[Thu Mar 01 18:32:03.219991 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 13753] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Thu Mar 01 18:32:03.220008 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 13753] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
```

My history on this is that I've taken a very good Python and Django course. I have 40 years programming experience so don't find coding a problem. I'm relatively new to Linux/Ubuntu and have spent over a week trying to get as little as a 'hello world' appearing on my browser. The documentation is not clear. For example, the official Django documentation recommends putting various settings in httpd.conf but there isn't one. I've tried just about every suggestion on SO into practice but nothing seems to work.

Now I guess this might be bad etiquette but I'm getting desperate and on the verge of giving up on Django. I would really like someone who knows their way around to help me out. I can reward with a suitable number of Amazon vouchers or goodies. I have RealVNC installed so you would be able to log in and have a look as there is nothing sensitive on the server yet. The truth of the matter is that I'm a developer and find the system admin/configuration side of things to be difficult. Thanks for your attention and hopefully you'll help me out.

Comment: I suggest go for nginx, gunicorn, circus setup instead of apache, as apache is not good to go for Django, blog is here http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/ If you trying on local server running on 8000 port is more enough.

Comment: A patch level difference in Python version is not an issue, only major/minor version difference. See the documentation at [modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/…](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#python-patch-level-mismatch)

Comment: Thanks Anup. I need this code to connect to the internet. Apache is currently serving the url www.factsfromfigures.com, or it would be if I could sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The path is incomplete at `<Directory /home/user/mycode/mysite/>`. It should be `<Directory /home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite>` (note that `mysite` should occur twice).

---

Anyway, from an old project, here's what my apache config file looks like:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

WSGIPythonPath /home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite

<Directory /home/user/mycode/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and restarted apache but same problem. Also, when I added the WSGIPythonPath parameter it would not restart the Apache server. I did a systemctl status apache2.service and it reports: WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section. I guess I should be adding that parameter to the httpd.conf but there isn't one. My virtual host is defined in a conf file that is registered with apache using the a2ensite command.

Comment: @tommccann Well, that's a bummer. I don't use Apache anymore so, can't really investigate this issue practically. But [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04#configure-apache) on configuring Apache to serve Django app seems good. Anyway, if you can switch to Nginx, I can certainly help you there.

Comment: Thanks for your help xyres. I'll keep on with the seemingly never-ending fiddling around. I'll try to follow that article.